# How can I express a conversion between number systems, in notation?

Tags: notation

I'd like to express the following in notation:

> Take the *DeviceID*, subtract one, and convert the result into the hexadecimal number system.

I'm writing documentation for a technical project, and would like to use the formula for similar conversions, instead of repeating myself. I planned on showing the formula once , including the text description, so someone who isn't familiar would understand it too. I found the following, but I'm not sure if it's correct: 
\begin{equation} [DeviceID-1]_{16} \end{equation}

Comment: It's more computer science related, than math related. It would depend on what base the numerical DeviceID was in. Lastly, it would likely be expressed as  a function in function notation, or a bijection between sets in set notation. The sets as posed, are undefined.

Comment: What you are proposing to do is just fine - particularly including the words. You coud avoid formulas altogether by choosing a good name for this transformation of the Device ID and writing it as a function: $\text{goodname}(ID)$. What makes a name good is context - what will best help your reader.